# PHPExcel unexpected float behavior

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm create a new PHPExcel object into one of my  projects and whats odd is how some float functions behave after the library is included.
Take for example the `round` function, it will not round after PHPExcel is included.

```
        echo round(90.00 + 9.71, 2); // outputs 99.71
        $sheet = new \PHPExcel();
        $sheet->getProperties()
            ->setCreator('Bob')
            ->setTitle('Title');

        echo round(90.00 + 9.71, 2); // outputs 99.7099999999
        exit;
```

Is there a way around this? I tried using `setValueExplict` but it says `PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING` is not found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comes down to PHPExcel modifying the php.ini `precision` setting in its calculation engine. You can override this yourself:

```
echo round(90.00 + 9.71, 2); // outputs 99.71

$savedPrecision = ini_get('precision');
$sheet = new \PHPExcel();
ini_set('precision', $savedPrecision);

echo round(90.00 + 9.71, 2); // outputs 99.71
```

or alternatively, use sprintf() or number_format() when you echo float values to get the number of decimals that you want to display

Comment: your answer works and i found that sprint() and number_format() are both producing the same trailing float results.

Comment: If You're telling sprint() and number_format() to display 2 decimals and they're displaying more, then either you've mistold them 2 decimals only, or you've found a hitherto unknown bug in both of those functions

Comment: i used `sprintf('%.2f', (90 + 9.71))` without setting `$savedPrecision` and the results were wrong. Maybe it works on the same precision setting as `round()`.

Comment: `sprintf('%.2f', (90 + 9.71))` is specifically telling sprint() to display to 2 decimal places, no more, no less, and it will round to 2dp regardless of the precision setting [Demo](http://ideone.com/OHV9jB)

Comment: Interesting, I will see if i can find what else might be going on. Thanks!